# Duplicates with additional information in answers

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

This happened to me just few minutes ago: I posted [How can I make Mathematica agree that 0^0 = 1?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151687/35000) since I could not find anything searching for `0^0` (why by the way?). Then [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) marked it as duplicate of [Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60575/35000), and I agreed with that, so now it is a duplicate.

However it already had a nice [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151688/35000) which contains information not quite available in the answer to that other question - for example, it shows how to do it in `init.m`.

I understand that this question is still available, but my question is: will somebody looking for it also find this additional information?

There is a related question [Coping with "abstract duplicates"/"variant questions"](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/237/35000) here on meta, but it is about variations in **questions** which in my case is not present, it is just additional information in answers that I worry about not losing.

Comment: Your question is now listed in "Linked" column. Therefore there is a chance that somebody looking for more solutions will find it, but probably most people ignore the column at the right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a moderator Merge function that forcibly and permanently moves all answers and comments from the "duplicate" to the "original" question.  This is at times appropriate but it is too heavy handed to be a matter-of-course operation.

Ideally in such cases the answerer would delete his existing answer and recreate it, with appropriate adjustment, as an answer to the original question, thereby keeping all methods in one place and directly comparable. (Because of a common reference and/or example.)

Admittedly that ideal doesn't happen every time (or even very often, honestly), so we are left with a lot unique answers scattered among duplicate questions.  A solution is for an interested person to Answer the original using the unique method that was posted in answer to the duplicate.